# Image upload in Yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have implemented image file upload in Yii framework. It is uploading the image and stores into database successfully, but images are not stored in my directory. In my controller I've added following code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Friends;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Friends']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Friends'];

                 $image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profile_image');
             if (is_object($image) && get_class($image)==='CUploadedFile') 
                {
                  $model->profile_image=$image->name;    
                }
                if($model->save())
            if(is_object($image))
            $image->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../friends_picture/'.$model->profile_image);   

        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Where is the error? The given directory name is correct or not?

Comment: dirname(__FILE__).'/../../friends_picture/'.$model->profile_image                 echo this statement and see whether this is the path where you want to store it or its producing wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Friends;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Friends']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Friends'];

        $model->profile_image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profile_image');

        if($model->save())

            $fullImgSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/friends_picture/'.$model->profile_image;
            $model->profile_image->saveAs($fullImgSource);


        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

May It help you.

Thanks

Comment: Update Code. Test it again

Answer (score 0):

just try this

$model->profile_image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profile_image');

```
    if($model->save())

        $fullImgSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/friends_picture/'.$model->profile_image;
        $model->profile_image->saveAs($fullImgSource);
```